# What is difference between outlays and expenses?

Tags: differences

Are these two words synonyms? If not, what is the difference between them?

Comment: More or less. Dictionaries suggest that _outlay_ (singular) is often used of the initial cost of something, while _expenses_ are often ongoing.

Comment: Thank you Kate.